# How to find accurate civil aviation flight traffic data?

Tags: commercial-aviation, helicopter, general-aviation, online-tracking, flight-tracking

I need to review civil aviation flight traffic data for several regions around the world.

My preference is real-time data, but data delayed by 5-15 minutes is fine.  Historical data (going back 1 year) works too, but is not quite as useful.

Ideally, I would like the data to include the aircraft type and registration number.

I'm not getting compensated to contribute to this project, so having the data be free is important.

I am aware of 2 websites that provide this information for free:

- [Flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com)
- [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com)

The challenge I have with those 2 sites is that the data appears to be incomplete.  Aircraft will be shown on one site, but not the other.  To make matters worse, some aircraft are completely missing from both sites.  I've noticed this, especially, for helicopter traffic (including near airports).  Including civil helicopter data is essential.

What other resources are available for this civil aviation flight traffic data?

Comment: "Resource location" is specifically [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

One such site is

https://globe.adsbexchange.com/

As for the problems you mentioned, I'm sure this one has them too, but adsbexhange does seem to provide a lot of data per target. It also has convinient and extensive filters availlable for free. I do not know if there is any history -function on this site.

Comment: Your recommendation is a big help.  Upvoted.  Thank you!